# Tfs_Configuration > tbl_Content database table grow fast

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

I have deployed TFS 2019 (Azure DevOps Server 2019). I have problem that my `Tfs_Configuration` database grow very fast (± 1 GB per month). 
Currently table `dbo.tbl_Content` have ±10 GBs. I do not use this TFS daily so for me is mystery why it grows so fast.

Especially why `Tfs_Configuration` database and not collection database.

What is stored in this table ? Is here way how to extract data from this table to more readable format ?

Had someone the same problem with configuration database ?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** table `dbo.tbl_Content` grow fast in database `Tfs_Configuration`

Comment: The `tbl_content` not growing?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes. Table `tbl_content` is the biggest in database. Whole database has 10GBs and from this size 8.8GB is consumed by table `tbl_content` and still growing

Comment: Do you use Git or TFVC? do you store binaries or only code?

Comment: I use mostly GIT, but i have several projects where is also TFVC. I store mostly only source code. But these data are stored in Collection database and not in configuration database .. or am i wrong ? II have problem with Table in configuration database

Comment: The `tbl_content` exist in the Configuration DB?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have it :)

Comment: Ok, `tbl_content` can grow fast in TFS from some reasons, 1GB per month is not so terrible... do you run Builds in TFS? tests?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk i give you example. During month May I did not change anything in TFS, I did not trigger any build. Literally i did nothing , but db is still growing.

Comment: @PeterM. did you get any solution? We are also running into same issues.

Comment: @undefined no :/.. maybe MS could provide some kind of admin tool to show content of this kind of data.. several time i thought if it could be nuget package store ... for example some kind of auto download of nugets from nuget.org i do not know :/